# Dynamically adjust font as per text content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

Lets say I have a UILabel or UITextView of frame 320*460
And if user type any letter A... it should go in to the middle with Big A.

And as soon as user keep writing further then Label font should adjust automatically. Obviously there should be some min and max range lets say min as 8pixel.

And yeah there is no functionality of scrolling.

Please help so that I can give initiation to my algorithm with 100% dynamic content irrespective of hardcoded frame size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the UITextFieldDelegate and or UITextInputDelegate based on the controls that you have. When the text is entered find the entire text and measure the maximum font that is possible with the frame that you have using the method

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;

This method is on the NSString